# Why an opinionated version of Jadira Usertypes is not included in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When defining a *pom.xml* using Spring Boot, it seems like I have to manually define the Jadira Usertypes version. I cannot find Jadira mentioned anywhere in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/).

Is there a specific reason Spring Boot doesn't provide an opinionated dependency to Jadira Usertypes?

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
    <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
    <version>__need_to_specify_version_here__</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Voting to close as this question is not suitable for SO... not sure why people downvote instead of voting to close :S.

Comment: Care to explain what's wrong about the question?

Comment: It's because it's asking for an opinion, and it's not related to software, rather to why a group made a decision. My opinion would be that not many people use that project, and as such is not worth considering it adding it in spring boot... as my backing, there's not even a 'jadira' tag in SO. The Jadira team could add their own autoconfig if they cared.

Comment: Spring Boot provides `opinionated 'starter' POMs to simplify your Maven configuration` (from [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)). *I am not asking for an opinion*: I am asking whether Spring Boot is not providing a specific version for Jadira Usertype because maybe it's not the best practice (since Spring Boot provides versions for tens of other artifacts) and it's more a question for those who use Spring Boot than for Jadira's team.

Comment: Tens of other artefacts which are broadly used by a large number of projects (e.g. Hibernate)... Can you imagine how it would be if they provide a starter module for each of the 10.000+ java open source libraries out there? If this is not enough of an explanation, I hope another SO user can help you.

Comment: It's not a matter of providing a starter module, but of setting a `version` tag, [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml). Do you use joda with Hibernate? If yes, what do you use to persist joda instances?

Comment: Typically the answer for those questions is always: Because nobody hasn't filed a feature request in the projects bugtracker yet or there aren't enough votes on such a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, Spring Boot only provides dependency management for artifacts that it depends upon and, typically, for which it has auto-configuration. Jadira doesn't fit either of these criteria so you have to specify a version manually.

Comment: Thanks Andy, so there isn't any preconfigured library for persisting joda or jdk 8 date instances. A developer must 'manually' load another dependency (such as jadira), correct?

Comment: Correct. To my knowledge you're the first person to ask about this so it doesn't appear to be bothering too many others.